# What is preferred, using setter or builder?

Tags: java, setter, builder

I have a class like this:

```
public class Team
{
    private final String id;

    private final String subOrgId;

    private final String teamName;

    private final String costCenter;

    private final String email;

    private final String seaSecurityGroup;

    private final String expesoSecurityGroup;

    public Team(final String id, final String subOrgId, final String teamName, final String costCenter,
            final String email, final String seaSecurityGroup, final String expesoSecurityGroup)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.subOrgId = subOrgId;
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.costCenter = costCenter;
        this.email = email;
        this.seaSecurityGroup = seaSecurityGroup;
        this.expesoSecurityGroup = expesoSecurityGroup;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSubOrgId()
    {
        return subOrgId;
    }

    public String getTeamName()
    {
        return teamName;
    }

    public String getCostCenter()
    {
        return costCenter;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public String getSeaSecurityGroup()
    {
        return seaSecurityGroup;
    }

    public String getExpesoSecurityGroup()
    {
        return expesoSecurityGroup;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a use case where in I need to set a new value of the ID in class Team. I am of the opinion that I should make a setter in the class for this (declare id as non-final) and use that. However, I also think that I should probably go ahead with making a builder and use that. While writing a setter is less work, but I want to make sure I am going ahead with the right pattern. What is recommended in such a case?

Thanks!

Comment: Only you know for sure, but this looks like any other POJO which could be a Javabean

Comment: In my opinion is a builder not the right pattern. When you want to use immutable objects you can add a setter which creates a new instance with only the setted value changed.

Comment: I wouldn't factor this immutable class into a mutable one without serious thought, if it's in use already assumptions have likely been made about it being immutable.

Answer (score 2):

The builder pattern is not meant to be used if one wants to change (single) attributes of an object.

> Builder pattern solves the issue with large number of optional
>   parameters and inconsistent state by providing a way to build the
>   object step-by-step and provide a method that will actually return the
>   final Object. [source: JournalDev](http://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java)

When you just want to update a single attribute of an existing class, using a `setter` is perfectly fine, that's what they are for, actually.

It is hard to assess if it makes sense to change the ID of that object without knowing the context of your application. Creating a new object with a new ID might be an option, too.

Comment: But why using builder at all if you can just create an empty object and then set each field? What's the advantage of using builder compared to this?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have provided, you have a lot of private variables to be set for the object and all these are final; using the builder pattern would be ideal in this situation. Setters are not very useful in this case, as its gonna be used only once (since all your object variables are final).

Do not make your 'id' variable non-final. I'm assuming your object can and will have only one constant 'id' value for the entire duration of its existence. This is exactly what 'final' was made for. Making it non-final completely defeats the purpose for which 'final' is in place.

So keep the 'id' variable 'final'. In your switch case, get whatever id value you want and put it into a variable, and when using the builder to build your Team object, use that id variable, outside your switch case.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

In First instance it looks like a java bean class (if that's all you want than have a getter and setter with a default constructor which is not present in your class, because I dont't like to have all the parameter passing in the constructor). Also, if in future you want to add let's say 4-5 variable then your code will break as you have to modify your constructor which can be avoided.

Second, then you are adding final to the variable and eliminating the setter's leading to the direction that you want to create a mutable class, then in that case you should also make your class as final.

Consider having builder pattern when face with so many parameter's in the constructor.

Also, you should not allow any setter property for the id. Instead create a new Instance with new Id value.
That's how mutability works and will be good to avoid new bug.